# Bluetooth icon in status bar on Android pie

Tags: bluetooth, notification-bar, notification-icons

Is it possible to display the bluetooth icon in the status (notification) bar on Android 9 pie (Bootleggers rom, to be more specific), when the device is not connected to any other devices through bluetooth?

I like to only enable different sensors/radios of the phone, when I need and use them. At other times, I like to keep them disabled. But sometimes I forget to disable bluetooth on the phone, after using it in the car.

I'm not 100% certain, but I think that the icon only appears when the phone connects to another device through bluetooth. And I'm sure that when bluetooth is enabled and the phone isn't connected to anything - there is no icon.

Comment: You can setup an automation app, such as Tasker and MacroDroid, to turn off Bluetooth immediately or after X amount of time once a bluetooth connection is no longer active.

Comment: Yes, good idea. But I would have to put some thought into what timeout to set. Because there are sometimes situations when the car is used to get to several different locations during the day and the pauses between drives can be 15 min to 4 hours, let's say. Alternatively I guess I could create a notification which asks if I'd like to turn off bluetooth already.

Comment: Trouble is that with my current rom I can't get the notification led to blink, using tasker (asked a question about it too https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213768/blink-notification-led-with-specific-apps-notification). So this notification can also be as easily missed, as forgetting to turn off bluetooth in the first case. But I guess it would have the same effect as the bluetooth icon in the taskbar.